# activerecord unscope like params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this query:

```
filtri = Interventi.where(chiuso: @f_stato, id: @array_int, cliente_id: @f_cliente, categoria: @f_categoria, intervento: @f_cerca).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')
if @f_cliente.blank?
     filtri = filtri.unscope(where: :cliente_id)
  end
```

i can simply unscope a params if it's not set:

```
if @f_stato.blank?
    filtri = filtri.unscope(where: :chiuso)
end
```

I need to add a search params, so i need a 'like' condition:

```
@f_cerca = params[:search] if params[:search]
  filtri = Interventi.where('chiuso = ? AND id = ? AND cliente_id = ? AND categoria = ? AND intervento like ?', @f_stato, @array_int, @f_cliente, @f_categoria, @f_cerca).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')
```

but with this second query i can't unscope a where clausole with:

```
if @f_cerca.blank?
    filtri = filtri.unscope(where: :intervento)
  end
```

as i did in first query

I think a way may be to convert all where clausole in 'like' and change params in '%' instead of unscope them...... is there any other way?

How can i solve?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use multiple `where`s instead of unscoping.

First query

```
filtri = Interventi.where(chiuso: @f_stato, id: @array_int, categoria: @f_categoria, intervento: @f_cerca)
if @f_cliente.present?
  filtri = filtri.where(cliente_id: @f_cliente)
end
filtri = filtri.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')
```

Second query

```
@f_cerca = params[:search]
filtri = Interventi.where('chiuso = ? AND id = ? AND cliente_id = ? AND categoria = ?', @f_stato, @array_int, @f_cliente, @f_categoria)
if @f_cerca.present
  filtri = filtri.where('intervento like ?', @f_cerca)
end
filtri = filtri.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')
```

Comment: Thanks , your suggestion is fine with some arrangement !